# SDL 2 linker error

Tags: c++, eclipse, sdl, linker-errors, sdl-2

I've been trying to setup SDL2 with eclipse(kepler) with mingw .
This is the code of what I am trying to compile and it seems to get built without any problems , no compilation errors . The .exe actually runs but does not respond (maybe because it's just a show that waits for 2000) , it also debugs but I have to skip this :
*Can't find a source file at "e:\p\giaw\src\pkg\mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src\bld/../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/main.c" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.*
This path is not present on my machine .

```
#include "SDL2/SDL_main.h"
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{ 
    SDL_Window *win = NULL;
    win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    SDL_Renderer *ren = NULL;
    ren = SDL_CreateRenderer(win, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED 
                                    | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC);
    SDL_Surface *bmp = NULL;
    bmp = SDL_LoadBMP("hello.bmp");
    SDL_Texture *tex = NULL;
    tex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(ren, bmp);
    SDL_FreeSurface(bmp);
    SDL_RenderClear(ren);
    SDL_RenderCopy(ren, tex, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(ren);
    SDL_Delay(2000);
    SDL_DestroyTexture(tex);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(ren);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

I hope someone encountered this and has any suggestions .

Comment: If it builds and creates an executable, then there is no linker error. The "problem" you have in the debugger is because that's a source file for the runtime library, and you can ignore that. So in short, you don't have any problems at all?

Comment: Well besides that , no , not really . But it is kind of annoying to see that and I was hoping for a fix for it .

Comment: 'Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location', the instruction seems clear enough?

Comment: Not exactly , since I don't really understand which SOURCE it has a problem finding . If you could be a little bit more explicit other than pointing out stuff that I have been reading for two days now , I would be very thankful .

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exactly fix it, but you can avoid the error message if you uncheck "Stop on startup at:" in the "Debugger" tab of "Debug Configurations".